# Sequence contains no matching elements - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I looked all over Stack Overflow for this exception and found a lot of questions about it, but none that could solve my problem.

I am unit testing my application. All the tests were passing until I put an index on a column of one of my entities. I am using ABP, also.

It's worth noting that the app works fine when I run it, using SQL Server, but my unit tests use an in-memory database.

This works:

```
[Required]
public string Name
{
   get { return PersonalInformation.Name; }
   set { PersonalInformation.Name = value; }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
[Index]
[Required]
public string Name
{
   get { return PersonalInformation.Name; }
   set { PersonalInformation.Name = value; }
}
```

The error "Sequence contains no elements" is thrown in a class I created that inherits from `AbpIntegratedTestBase`, in the first line of this method:

```
public void UsingDbContext(Action<UnitTestDbContext> action) {
    using (var context = LocalIocManager.Resolve<UnitTestDbContext>())
    {
        action(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? I'm trying to solve this for 3 days ^^"

Comment: You always have to look into the stack trace to see where the exception is thrown, we can't do that for you. Also, you seem to use some global filter library but you don't mention it in your question.

Comment: Also, it's highly uncommon and probably not exception-proof to have mapped delegated (dotted) properties: `PersonalInformation.Name`. You have to fix that first.

Comment: After your edit: *but my unit tests use an in-memory database* - Face it, the in-memory database can't be expected to behave identical to Sql Server. It's meant to provide mock data while *using* your data-access code but not for *testing* the data access code. Anyway, no clue as long as you don't show the stack trace. Also showing `PersonalInformation` and the class containing the above properties would help.